# How to connect my laptop to my campus network through internet?

Tags: networking

I have a laptop with internet connection. I want to access the computer, which is connected to the campus network, in my lab through my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Ask to your campus admin.
If you have his agreement, he'll tell you how to do it.

I dont think you can install your own solution without his agreement, it could be a network security issue.